# Who or whom? "Figure 1 depicts a surveillance system, detecting pedestrians whom are crossing dangerous regions."

Tags: pronouns, case, who-whom

In the following sentence, should I use who or whom? It is highlighted in bold.

> For instance, Figure 1.1 depicts an operating smart surveillance system, detecting pedestrians **whom** are crossing dangerous regions, cars in parking lots, and ships.

I think it should be **whom** because the "operating smart surveillance system" is the subject, while "pedestrians" are the object. But, my professor corrected it to who and now I'm not sure.

Comment: The relative clause should start with **who**: "X are crossing regions". Regions: object. X: subject. But it's good that you've explained your reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system is subject but then the next clause talks about pedestrians who also *become* subject crossing the regions etc. Removing the pronoun itself will also work.

A quick trick!

Now, cut off the sentence.

> Pedestrians whom are crossing [something]

Here only, we get a hint that it seems incorrect.

Now, think that it's about 'you'. If *'I'* fits, put *'who'* and if *'me'* fits, put *'whom'*.

> ***<del>me</del> I*** am crossing [something]

Technically, if the pronoun in question is *doing* something, prefer putting **'who'** (what they call subject) and if it's receiving something, prefer **'whom'** (what they call object)!

Comment: An even easier way to remember it, since they both either end in 'm' or a vowel, is "whom" goes where "him" would go, and "who" goes where "he" would go.

Answer (score 1):

Pedestrians is the subject of the sub-clause "pedestrians who are crossing...".  I think the professor is right.