# Is "Whom" a deprecated word?

Tags: pronouns

I'm learning English through online courses.

I'm enrolled at the Write101x, managed by University of Queensland, Australia.

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8a7UQe82tnY about 2:47 minutes, the lady says the following:

> Many writers believe that 'whom' is on its way out because it can
>   sound very pompous. Some even believe it’s circling the drain.
>   However, it is still used in expressions like ‘to whom it may
>   concern’. In the sentence ‘the girl whom you’ve been dancing with is
>   on her way to the top’, most writers would use ‘who’ rather than
>   ‘whom’, and it’s fine to do that.

I'm not sure about what she meant.

**Should I replace 'whom' by 'who' in every sentence** (but still using in traditional cases like 'to whom it may concern')?

OR

**Should I try to replace 'whom' by 'who' whenever it is possible** (like in the sentence: ‘the girl whom you’ve been dancing with is  on her way to the top’) ?

Comment: This is a really complicated question and will be really difficult to answer objectively... and I'll bet you're going to hear more people against dropping "whom" than for it... which I agree with... the reality is that, in common usage (depending on where you are), the word is becoming more obscure... that **does not** mean that it's improper to use or that you should intentionally remove it from your vernacular.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, do you think it is okay to replace 'who' by 'whom' in **every sentence**?

Comment: ... I'd also point out that "most writers" would probably write "The girl you've been dancing with is on her way to the top"... As far as I'm concerned, neither the who nor whom is necessary.

Comment: That's what I mean by "it's difficult to be objective"... **personally** I would not recommend using "who" when "whom" is appropriate... that is not the response that everyone will tell you, though... it's largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: I agree with @Catija that this question is more about style, opinion, or class/status positioning than correctness. If you can use it consistently and correctly, I would keep using *whom*, but be aware that it can sound pompous or over-educated in casual situations. And the idea of avoiding the issue by omitting the pronoun entirely is also a good one.

Comment: @Catija As far as I know, who never can be an object. Also whom never can be a subject.

Comment: My grammar book says it is wrong to say "the man whom killed .. " ,but "the man who killed the .."

Comment: I don't think it sounds pompous to use _whom._ Don't dwell on it or stress it unduly, and it will just sound like you have a good command of the language.  HOWEVER:  Incorrectly using _whom_ when _who_ is called for (e.g. _Fig 1 depicts a system detecting people whom are crossing regions._ http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47234/who-or-whom-figure-1-depicts-a-surveillance-system-detecting-pedestrians-whom?rq=1 ) sounds awful.  My advice:  Use _whom_ when you are confident that it is correct.  If in doubt, use _who_, because it sounds much better to err in that direction than the other.

Comment: @Cardinal that is the rule, yes. The issue is that it's an often ignored rule. I'd bet the average American is unable to tell you if who or whom is appropriate in a situation.

Comment: @Catija So, why I cannot find anything like "the man whom killed ...". Also I've never heard anything like that (I mean News, Books, ...)

Comment: @Cardinal likely because the default choice is "who"... Not whom.

Comment: @Cardinal - Probably because people who aren't sure whether to use _who_ or _whom_ usually (almost always) default to using _who._

Comment: English really isn't as rigorous as you might imagine. Usage of the word whom will depend on whom you ask. Technically, there is always a "right" answer, but most natives couldn't tell you without looking it up. Here's a little thing that might help you out, though: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/who_vs_whom.

Comment: "The girl with whom you've been dancing" if you are using 'whom'. "The girl whom you've been dancing with" sounds like a mishmash of styles.

Comment: Does "pompous" include people who don't know how to use the word but think they'll sound clever if they stick it anywhere that _who_ should go? Because there seem to be plenty of those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question from the point of view of interpreting what's said in the video, specifically... I think this is one of the main points of your question and I think understanding that will help you understand the wonderful world that is "who vs whom".

Let's look at what she says, first:

> Many writers believe that 'whom' is on its way out because it can sound very pompous.

As you've seen in the comments, there are differing opinions on this... my personal feeling is that, in the relaxed, informal world of spoken English, this is more likely and in the more formal world of written English, it's less likely to feel pompous.

> Some even believe it’s circling the drain.

Probably true to some degree. Note she says "some"... she doesn't say "it's widely believed to be circling the drain" - the idiom here meaning it's on the way out of popular use.

As I've stated in a comment, if you gave the average American a question about whether "who" or "whom" was appropriate in a series of sentences, they'd likely get it wrong. **I** probably get it wrong occasionally.

> However, it is still used in expressions like ‘to whom it may concern’.

Yes... but it's a bit [reductive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reductive) to imply that this is the *only* place it's regularly used. I'd argue this is simply a better-known idiom, so more people are likely to know that *this* is an example of the correct usage.

> In the sentence ‘the girl whom you’ve been dancing with is on her way to the top’

There's a couple things about this sample sentence that I feel are suboptimal:

- She's split the preposition off of the object, "whom", by rearranging the sentence.
- I, personally, wouldn't use either "who" or "whom" in this particular arrangement of the sentence.

**Better** versions of the sentence (in my mind) would be to either omit the pronoun entirely

> *the girl you’ve been dancing with is on her way to the top*

or to keep the preposition before the object

> *the girl with whom you’ve been dancing is on her way to the top*

Now, at least, including the pronoun makes some sense to me. I still prefer the version without "whom" as this version feels a bit odd or [stilted](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stilted) to me.

I suppose the rearrangement could be an Australian construction but I'm not sure.

> most writers would use ‘who’ rather than ‘whom’, and it’s fine to do that.

This is, I think, where the main crux of the question comes in. I think it's bad teaching to say "most writers do X"... I disagree that "most writers" would use the construction in her sample. Regardless of that, she says "it's fine to do that"... and that is true. It may be a *technically* ungrammatical choice to use "who" but it is not an uncommon *actual* use.

That being said, she only says "it's fine to use who in place of whom", which is *generally* true... what she does **not** say is "don't use whom".

So, in relation to the two options in your question, the answer is, "**neither**". You are quite welcome to use (or continue to use) "whom" appropriately. There is no reason to intentionally use "who" when you know that "whom" is correct. If you're **unsure** which is correct, it's acceptable in many circles to use "who" in all cases... but don't be startled if someone corrects you.

From my point of view, saying "*to who were you speaking*" sounds wrong... because it should be "whom". There are [some](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom) great [references](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly) in our network for proper usage of who and whom and encourage you to check them out for more information.

Comment: Such a discussion just calls for the inevitable [Abbott and Costello](http://www.psu.edu/dept/inart10_110/inart10/whos.html) link :)

Comment: Oh we can do better than that.  Here's the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTcRRaXV-fg)

Comment: "It may be a technically ungrammatical" <-- Technically, there isn't such a thing as 'technically ungrammatical'.

Answer (score 32):

Words don't get "deprecated" the way APIs do.   They may gradually fall out of use, but they're not scheduled for obsolescence.

The word *whom* will continue to function for a long time, in written works, long after Microsoft has stopped supporting Windows 20.

Comment: Informative, and quirky. 1+

Comment: Microsoft has announced that they will not release any new Windows after Windows 10 !. (Irrelevant )

Comment: @Cardinal At last!

Comment: @Cardinal, is that ten factorial?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @TRomano that ***whom*** will continue to "function" for at least a few more generations. So *if you use it correctly*, it's quite okay to carry on.

You can even get away with using in wrongly sometimes. Not all native speakers will recognize every misuse (they might just assume you know better! :)

But definitely the *easiest* option is not to bother with it at all - unless you're *certain* it's correct, in which case it's really just a judgement call/style choice.

---

EDIT: In all fairness, *to whom it may concern* is so well-known almost every native speaker would probably notice if you switched to ***who*** there. But if you ask *To who am I speaking?*, I doubt the average telephone receptionist would notice anything wrong (or unusual - it happens all the time).

Comment: Of course, "Who am I speaking to?" is the current idiomatic way of saying it.

Comment: @John: Indeed. I put it that way because I didn't want my hypothetical pedantic telephonist objecting to *Whom am I speaking to?* on the grounds that ending a sentence with a preposition is wrong anyway. Perhaps I should have chosen an example like *Who did you see?* But although according to the basic Victorian/Latin "rule" that also should be ***whom***, I suspect many of the people who still use it at all would only do so following a preposition. It's all a bit of a mess - half-remembered rules half-heartedly adhered to by people who haven't yet moved on.

Comment: Yes, so I would say "To whom am I speaking?" is the standard pedantic way of saying it, and "Who am I speaking to?" is the standard colloquial way, but mixing them just sounds odd to me.

Comment: @John: Noting the current votes on this page, I have some sympathy with our target audience of *learners* here on ELL. My answer (effectively saying *Don't waste your time learning how to use **whom***) only has 4 upvotes, but there are 23 upvotes for TRomano's answer (which strongly implies *You need to learn this, because it's part of standard English*). My guess is most of the latter upvotes are from non-native speakers thinking ***I** had to learn it, and I'm damned if I'm going to admit I wasted my time, so I'm gonna upvote this answer implying it's a useful lesson well learned*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, then, we need to recruit to the site more Americans who are determined to show Mrs. Blashfield, their 3rd grade teacher, that we need _fewer_ words, not _more_ (or I should rather say _less words_...) and that she was poking at the last embers of a quenched fire, and that she can take the whole damned objective case with her to the grave.

Answer (score 5):

Language is changing constantly as we can see in the case of the accusative or object form "whom" (question word and relative pronoun).

In colloquial language "whom" has vanished. The m has simply been dropped.

In written formal language "whom" is still used.

It is not a matter of deprecation, but one of up-coming new usage (at first always in spoken language) with the older original form being kept in formal written language for a long time.

Comment: Related [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=shrinkage+of+the+english+vocabulary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 4):

They are different parts of speech.  "Who" is a subject noun, "whom" is an object noun.  A quick-and-dirty way to determine which form is correct is to substitute "he" for "who" and "him" for "whom", it's generally easier to hear which form is correct:

Example 1:
"He gave the ball to Jack."  OR  "Him gave the ball to Jack."  ?
"He" sounds correct, so the sentence "Who gave the ball to Jack" is what you want.

Example 2:
"Jill gave the ball to he."  OR  "Jill gave the ball to him."  ?
"him" sounds correct, so the sentence "Jill gave the ball to whom?" is what you want.

As others have answered, "who" is used incorrectly in many cases and has snuck into the vernacular, but I wouldn't say it's on it's way out.

> Should I replace 'whom' by 'who' in every sentence (but still using in
>   traditional cases like 'to whom it may concern')?
>
> OR
>
> Should I try to replace 'whom' by 'who' whenever it is possible (like
>   in the sentence: ‘the girl whom you’ve been dancing with is on her way
>   to the top’) ?

No.  Determine which form is correct, and use it.

Comment: +1 both for the he/him substitution method to clearly define proper usage (I think this method is universally correct; I can't think of any example sentence that would disobey this rule), and for pointing out explicitly that using either word exclusively would be incorrect. If I could vote up twice...

Comment: No, they are not nouns, they are pronouns. And "determining which form is correct" only makes sense in the context of what actual native speakers _currently_ do. Otherwise, it's the equivalent of insisting on ye vs. you.

Comment: @JohnPeyton whoops yep you are correct! They are pronouns.

Comment: How does the he/him or she/her trick work in "the girl whom you’ve been dancing with"?

Comment: @sheß Yes, it's not perfect.  You'd need to rearrange the original sentence somewhat.  Some would say it needs rearranging anyway, since it ends with a preposition, but that's another matter.

Rearrange to: the girl with whom you've been dancing, then substitute- "the girl, with her you have been dancing" is preferable to "with she you have been dancing".

Answer (score -6):

I, myself, find using whom as being proper...
Whom should I address this to? Versus ~ Who should I address this to? 
Though both are acceptable one is proper grammar.
Over the years our American English language has gotten sloppy or should I say lazy.
Who are you? Obviously would sound grammatically awkward if we asked Whom are you? 
If I said, He is my friend, who I have known for years. (Or) He is my friend whom I have known for years. The second one appears to give emphasis of friendship over the first as more of an acquaintance / friend. 
Though we are American, we still give some quasi credit to the Queen's English / British, of strength and value.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! "We" are actually from all over the globe. "You" might be American, though. ;)

Comment: Thank you. As to my answer that is why I also made mention that "Whom" was more closely related to emphasis toward relationship AND the fact as proper relating to colonial times when Great Britain cast their net around the world.

Comment: " Though we are American" We are? Nobody ever told me.

Comment: It's worth noting that a more natural construction for the example given is "He is my friend, that I have known for years". You wouldn't say "He I have known for years" or "Him I have known for years", so it makes sense that neither "who" nor "whom" is used. Also, the only use I'm aware of, of the phrasing "Whom are you?", is Alice in Wonderland (the cartoon - I couldn't even tell you if it was used in the original book) - "Who are you" because "I am you" or "He is you" - it's clearly a subject, not an object, in that position in the question.

Comment: I spent a few minutes trying to parse _the fact as proper relating to colonial times_ and finally concluded that it has no meaning, no matter to whom it is addressed.