# "Who" or "whom" in this relative clause

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, relative-pronouns

> We have just interviewed an applicant who the committee believes is best qualified for the position.
>
> We have just interviewed an applicant whom the committee believes is best qualified for the position.

Which is grammatically correct and what is difference between them?

When and how to use **who** and **whom** in this type of sentences? Please explain to me.

Comment: I think you may like this post:http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65647/is-whom-a-deprecated-word

Comment: @JavaLatte@Cardinal Thanks for providing the link. So, that means both can be right here? Or any one of above sentences is wrong? My book shows second is wrong. Could you please clarify me.

Comment: "Who" is correct. "Who(m)" is not the object of "believe" (though it may seem to be) but the **subject** of the content clause "who is best qualified ..." embedded within the relative clause, and hence it must be the **subjective** case "who". We understand that the committee believes (that) "who", i.e. "the applicant", is best qualified for the job. Note that personal pronouns as subject of finite clauses take subjective case "he/she/we" etc., not objective "him/her/us" etc.

Comment: Everyone of those who came here **are** foolish and cannot be relied upon. Could you please explain me whether **are** is right or wrong here. I think who refers to "those" which is plural so we can use "are". Am I right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ganesh.R It's a bit of a grey area. 'Every' is usually a distributive pronoun. This means that we are thinking about each person as an individual, and it normally takes singular verb agreement. "Every one was boreken", not "*Every one were broken". So **is** is probably best in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relative clause is

> who/whom  the committee believes is best qualified for the position.

You rewrite the relative clause putting a blank (_____) in where the relative pronoun goes:

> the committee believes ______ is best qualified for the position.

You substitute the relative clause into the blank: either *who* or *whom*. If you are unsure which one is correct, then substitute either *she* or *her*. If *she* is correct use *who*; if *her* is correct, use *whom*.

(The correct answer here is *who*, since *she* and not *her* is correct.)

---

Note I've written this "easy and quick" answer because the original poster still did not know the answer after looking at the possible duplicated question(s), which, by the way, contain a morass of information– much of it confusing and some of it bad.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the  question links that have been suggested  may have contained an answer to your question *somewhere* (along with some not so good information),  but I also know you looked the first link, at least,  and were still unsure of the answer.

Comment: I looked both the links but still unsure. Since I am not a native speaker it's a bit difficult for me to understand those explanations. I found that we can write who instead of whom but I can't find good explaination like yours for how to use them. You've explained the way that a novice can understand very well.

Comment: @Ganesh.R _Whom_ is the _objective case_ of _who_. Use of _whom_ is usually correct when "who" is the _object_ of a preposition or the _direct or indirect object_ of a verb. If those terms aren't clear to you, you might want to start at the beginning by learning and understanding basic English grammar and _parts of speech_ at a site like [this one](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/basic-english-grammar-rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think "who" is correct, because it acts as the subject in the clause " who is the best qualified for the position", which acts as an object of the verb " believe".